# Issue creating a custom role on Airflow (viewer + trigger dag + run dag permissions)

Tags: permissions, airflow, roles

On Airflow 1.10.1, I had a role with all viewer permissions + ״can trigger on Airflow״ + ״can run on Airflow״, that worked as expected (The user was able to view and run dags and tasks, but nothing else).

After Upgrading to Airflow 1.10.9, the user with the above role can't run dags and tasks anymore (even though the permissions are still a part of the role).

I tried adding a "can dag edit on all_dags" permission, but it added **all** edit permissions (clear, delete, set success, etc) and I want to avoid that.

I can't find any good documentation on how to do this.
Is it still possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I also didn't found a solution if not adding the "can dag edit on all_dags" permission to the role